# Global NPM Packages Installed, but executables not found, Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am on a Windows 10, for work reasons, I have an admin-level account, and a non-admin-level account. I generally have to sign in with the non-admin level account, but then utilize the admin when permissions are needed, anyways.

When using the admin account, if I install a package globally, it then can't be found:

```
$ npm install -g jshint
C:\.npm-global\jshint -> C:\.npm-global\node_modules\jshint\bin\jshint
$ jshint --help
bash: jshint: command not found
```

If I run `npm list -g`, it does list the packages.

I've attempted to create this shared `C:\.npm-global` folder to house global packages. I have set the npm prefix:

```
$ npm config get prefix
C:\.npm-global
```

and set `C:\.npm-global` in my user variables Path, and Sys Variables Path. My understanding is that after setting the npm prefix, and adding to the Path that this should work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems like an OS debugging issue.  Find where in your file system the `jshint` executable is that you're trying to run when you type `jshint --help` at the command line.  Then, figure out why the OS isn't looking in that location (probably related to what's in the path in your environment).

Comment: @jfriend00, agreed, I'm just not sure what to debug b/c the location of the global node modules and their executables IS in the Path variables. So, I'm not sure why it's not looking there.

Comment: Does it work when running from a regular Windows command shell?  Your error message makes it appear you're using a bash command prompt.  Perhaps it is something related to the bash configuration and it isn't using the Path you want it to.  Do you have a different path set in `.bashrc`?

Comment: It does not work when running from a regular windows command shell. It does work if I use the non-admin account (the npm config settings are the exact same).

Comment: and, you're right, those were from the VS Code built in git bash terminal.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the location jshint is installed is available to the admin?  Can you run it manually from the admin account if you run it with the full path?  If so, it sure seems like it has to be a path issue, perhaps a minor typo in the path that is hard to recognize.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for the delay. Yes, it's accessible. It's right on my C drive, and it works if I execute it directly